# Why this calculation of weight vector in linear regression is only for small dataset?

Tags: nlp, regression, gradient-descent

Slides from my university says, that the following way of calculating the weight vector is suitable only for small datasets. Can you please explain, why it may be suitable for small datasets?[image]

Here, X is observed variable and Y is dependent variable{usually 0 or 1}

Comment: I was actually curious as well. I remembered reading in Linear Models with R that Faraway mentioned something like this in his book. I looked up the passage and he says that

> This is a very bad way to compute . It is inefficient and can be very
> inaccurate when the predictors are strongly correlated. Such problems
> are exacerbated by large datasets.

Which was great and all, but that doesn't really tell me why.

Comment: I thought that for the large dataset, we may have X matrix very sparse and thats why the calculation may lead to overflow... But if it depends upon the correlation between the variables, then there must be some other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is your design matrix (data), so can get large, both in number of data points and number of predictors. The issues are indeed:

- Forming $XX^T$ may be computationally expensive
- Computing it explicitly may be inaccurate due to floating-point roundoff, as you're adding lots of products
- Inverting a matrix can be expensive here if the number of predictors is large as the Gramian is large
- With lots of predictors and a big Gramian, it's more likely to be ill-conditioned and suffer from numerical instability